# Why am I getting an error about a missing unstable trait (std::iter::Step - which the compiler will not let me implement) when compiling stable code?

Tags: for-loop, rust, iterator, range

I would like to define a function which should allow me to return an iterator over a range of struct instances.

I've tried the same functionality for standard types such as usize (see simplified code sample) and this works (although it is a little awkward). I can't use a standard type in the scenario that I have in mind, so that's not helpful to a solution, but it's helped me understand there is some kind of problem here.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyThing();

fn main() {
    let good  = 0usize..=10usize;
    // ALSO WORKS for thing in *good.start()..=*good.end() {
    for thing in 0usize..=10usize {
        dbg!(thing);
    }
    dbg!(good);

    let bad  = MyThing()..=MyThing();
    for thing in *bad.start()..=*bad.end() {
        dbg!(thing);
    }
    dbg!(bad);
}
```

```
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.35.0 (6f3e9c367 2019-04-04)

$ cargo build
   Compiling huh v0.1.0 (huh)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyThing: std::iter::Step` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:18
   |
13 |     for thing in *bad.start()..=*bad.end() {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::iter::Step` is not implemented for `MyThing`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::ops::RangeInclusive<MyThing>`
```

I don't expect the stable compiler to tell me that I have a missing unstable trait. I might have some other kind of issue here, which I don't understand, but the stable compiler is telling me that my problem is that I haven't implemented an unstable trait. I definitely can't fix my code like that (without switching to unstable).

I guess what I'm trying to understand is whether or not it's possible to define a range based on a user defined type which can then be iterated over.

Can anyone explain what is going on and suggest ways I can address my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::ops::RangeInclusive<MyThing>`
> ```

The `Step` trait is not yet stabilised. However, as this error note suggests, it is still used internally; the `Iterator` implementation of `Range*` types relies on the `Step` being implemented.

The result of this is that you cannot (yet) implement `Iterator` for ranges over custom types, until `Step` (or some replacement API) is stabilised.

---

Note that "unstable" in Rust does not mean it is buggy or could break in any way. It just means that there is still a possibility that the API could change in the future and break backwards-compatibility. The Rust compiler can make use of such APIs for syntax desugaring, because it can just change the desugaring later in the same release as the API changing.

---

To address the problem, I would suggest iterating over something else, that can be trivially converted into your type. Your code is perhaps a little too simplified to offer something realistic for your actual use case, but something along these lines:

```
impl From<usize> for Thing {
    fn from(index: usize) -> Thing {
        Thing()
    }
}

for i in 0..=10 {
    let thing = Thing::from(i);
    dbg!(thing);
}
```

This should not result in any performance overhead.

Comment: I probably can achieve what I wish as you describe, thanks for the suggestion and explanation. On the more general point of "could the compiler be more helpful in these kinds of situations" - I guess this is something that more experienced Rustaceans are aware of.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible for you to implement that trait on a stable compiler (as of 1.36.0) at the moment.

This "pattern" isn't uncommon in the Rust world, e.g. see the [`Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html) trait, which is used in [`str::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find) method, so you can use either Strings, chars or a closure to search for something.

Unstable means in this context that the actual signature of the trait may change and therefore it is not stabilized. If you use the unstable (aka nightly) compiler you opt-in that your code may break because the signature of a trait, function changes.